# asymptotics of the solution of an integral equation

Tags: probability-distributions, asymptotics, integral-equations

Suppose we are given the integral equation
$$
u(x;a)
=v(x)+\int_0^a K(x,y)\,u(y;a)\,dy,
$$
where $K(x,y)$ and $v(x)$ are known functions, and $a>0$ is a constant. What I am interested in is the asymptotic behavior of the solution $u(x;a)$ as $a\to\infty$. Is there a standard method of some kind to approach this problem?

To be more specific, suppose $v(x)=1$ for all $x$ and
$$
K(x,y)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} P\left(\frac{y}{x}\right),
$$
where $P(t)$ is the cdf of a nonnegative random variable, so $\int_0^\infty dP(t)=1$. Many thanks.

Comment: Provided the kernel $K(x,y)$ is well-behaved I would expect that the value of $u(x,a)$ for $a$ tending to infinity is given by the solution of $$u(x,∞)=v(x)+∫_{0}^{∞}dyK(x,y)u(y,∞)$$

Comment: Sure, but in this case $u(x,a)\to\infty$, as $a\to\infty$, and my question was about the specific way $u(x,a)$ goes to infinity as $a\to\infty$.

Comment: Yes, in your special case the kernel is not well-behaved.